# Spring Boot - How to call method from a service class just by the provided service class name?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I need to execute some method from a service class that is specified in the call from an API request controller. I have a POST request that receives a service class name, a request body that contains some variables and a size parameter for some operations in that method. The method is always called `getFilteredResults` no matter from what service class is being called. I don't have any clue from what class service is going to execute the method, except by the name of service class that is being provided in the url path:

```
@PostMapping(value = "method-call/{serviceClassName}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object executeMethod(@PathVariable("serviceClassName") String serviceClassName,
  @RequestBody Filter filter, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer size) {
  // ...
  // need to execute getFilteredResults(filter, size) from serviceClassName
  // ...
}
```

The requested service class, no matter the name is always like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

  @Autowired
  SomeDao someDao;

  public List<SomeEntity> getFilteredResults(Filter filter, Integer size) {
    return this.someDao.findAll(filter, PageRequest.of(0, size)).getContent();
  }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "method-call/{serviceClassName}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object executeMethod(@PathVariable("serviceClassName") String serviceClassName,
  @RequestBody Filter filter, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer size) {
  try {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(serviceClassName));
    Method getFilteredResults = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getFilteredResults", Filter.class, Integer.class);
    getFilteredResults.setAccessible(true);
    return getFilteredResults.invoke(cls.newInstance(), filter, size);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
    e.getCause().printStackTrace();
    return e;
  }
}
```

I get the service class with `Class.forName`, then I get the method with `Method getFilteredResults = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getFilteredResults", Filter.class, Integer.class)`, then I invoke the method from the service class with parameters this way: `getFilteredResults.invoke(cls.newInstance(), filter, size)`. No matter what I do, always throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

If I print the class and the method, they look like they're alright:

```
class co.com.company.fpv.service.SomeService
public java.util.List co.com.company.fpv.service.SomeService.getFilteredResults(co.com.company.fpv.service.filter.Filter,java.lang.Integer)
```

What am I doing wrong? or what else can I do to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will have a

> big security issue

with the design you are following. Basically you are allowing to call any method on any class with reflection. Call the services with their individual controllers or write if /else blocks.
Also, you are messing up with DI of the spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using Spring to inject beans and select the appropriate bean by name instead of relying on class names and reflection.

For example, if all service beans implemented a common interface like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements FilteredResultsService {

  @Autowired
  SomeDao someDao;

  @Override
  public List<SomeEntity> getFilteredResults(Filter filter, Integer size) {
    return this.someDao.findAll(filter, PageRequest.of(0, size)).getContent();
  }
}
```

Then you could inject all services that implement that interface into the controller:

```
// a Map of Spring beans of type FilteredResultsService, where
// the key is the name of the bean and the value is the bean object
@Autowired
private Map<String, FilteredResultsService> serviceBeans;

@PostMapping(value = "method-call/{serviceName}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object executeMethod(@PathVariable("serviceName") String serviceName,
  @RequestBody Filter filter, @RequestParam(required = false) Integer size) {

  FilteredResultsService service = serviceBeans.get(serviceName);
  if (service == null) {
    // invalid serviceName, throw an error
  } 

  return service.getFilteredResults(filter, size);
}
```

This would reduce the security risks pointed out by @syed-afzal, because only the beans created by your Spring configuration could be invoked, not any class on the classpath.